# Vuejs Reactivity Speed When Holding *delete* key on Keyboard

Tags: javascript, vue.js, validation, vuejs2

In Vuejs I'm listening on an `<input>` using `@input` attribute, so when the `input` field is empty a message shows `"Name cannot be blank"` it is working fine EXCEPT when I hold on delete button on the keyboard so deletion is done very quick, Vuejs doesn't catch it and the `"name is valid!"` shows

HTML:

```
<input type="text" v-model="newName" @input="checkName" class="input is-small">
<span ref="nameMsg" class="inline-block text-xs ml-4 mt-2">{{nameMsg}}</span>
```

The method on `@input('checkName')` :

```
checkName(e){
    
    let name = e.target.value; // also tried let name = this.newName
    let value = name.trim();
    console.log(value.length); // As shown on screen
    if(value.length == 0){
        this.nameMsg = "A name cannot be blank"
        return;
    }else if(value.length < 2){
        this.nameMsg = "A name length cannot be less than 2"
        return;
    }else{

        axios({
            method: 'get',
            url: `/${value}`
        }).then(res=>{
            this.nameMsg = res.data // "name is valid"
        }).catch(err=>{
            this.nameMsg = err.response.data.msg; // "name not valid"
        })
    }
    
}
```

And on server I have this so `nameMsg` doesnt get asyncly overridden by axios

```
if(name length > 1) return validation messages
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be debouncing your input. This will prevent the server from being called over and over again while you are deleting and wait for the event to complete.

#### If you are **not** using lodash

Install [debounce](https://www.npmjs.com/package/debounce) (12 KB unpacked)

```
npm i debounce
```

Import Debounce

```js
import debounce from debounce
```

Debounce your function by wrapping your function inside of the debounce function.

For example

```js
debounce(function(event){
   //Do cool stuff here
}, OptionalTimeout);
```

If you wanted to control, how long it took for events to stop being triggered before you made your API call, you can set the timeout.

```js
checkName: debounce((e) => {
    
    let name = e.target.value; // also tried let name = this.newName
    let value = name.trim();
    console.log(value.length); // As shown on screen
    if(value.length == 0){
        this.nameMsg = "A name cannot be blank"
        return;
    }else if(value.length < 2){
        this.nameMsg = "A name length cannot be less than 2"
        return;
    }else{

        axios({
            method: 'get',
            url: `/${value}`
        }).then(res=>{
            this.nameMsg = res.data // "name is valid"
        }).catch(err=>{
            this.nameMsg = err.response.data.msg; // "name not valid"
        })
    }
    
}, 250); /* timeout - set to 250ms for this example, change it if you want/need */
```

---

#### If you **are** using lodash

There is no need to install another package. [As lodash has always had debouncing built-in](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#debounce).

Just import lodash like normal

```
import _ from "lodash";
```

Or if you wanna get fancy, and reduce your bundle size (assuming you do this for all lodash imports)

```
import debounce from "lodash/debounce";
```

Debounce your function

```js
checkName: _.debounce((e) => {
    
    let name = e.target.value; // also tried let name = this.newName
    let value = name.trim();
    console.log(value.length); // As shown on screen
    if(value.length == 0){
        this.nameMsg = "A name cannot be blank"
        return;
    }else if(value.length < 2){
        this.nameMsg = "A name length cannot be less than 2"
        return;
    }else{

        axios({
            method: 'get',
            url: `/${value}`
        }).then(res=>{
            this.nameMsg = res.data // "name is valid"
        }).catch(err=>{
            this.nameMsg = err.response.data.msg; // "name not valid"
        })
    }
    
}, 250); /* timeout - set to 250ms for this example, change it if you want/need */
```